# Google Chrome, Linux, Wayland, UI scaling?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, gnome, wayland

Under Gnome 43.4, I enabled Wayland mode for Chrome with...
[image]

but in Wayland mode, the `--force-device-scale-factor` command-line option seems to behave weirdly. It does not scale the UI, but just makes the window smaller, cropping the window, making it unusable.

Is this a bug? Is there any way to adjust Chrome's UI scaling **other than** display scaling that affects other applications? Fractional scaling causes problems in Linux, so I used Gnome's font scaling instead, but it seems Chrome ignores font scaling.

Comment: Because of that I've migrated to Firefox. And I like it. It's a way better on Wayland session.

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact issue here on Arch and couldn't find a solution to that issue. Temporarily fixed it by changing the Page Zoom value to 110% in the Appearance section of Chrome's settings, though. Hope that helps

Comment: Page zoom applies only to the web page, not the GUI of Chrome itself, like the menu.

Comment: @DamnVegetables Yes, but this is applied to all web pages, and, in my case, have fixed the issue; that is, the font size on all web pages is way too small - which I tried to fix by using the `--force-device-scale-factor` option but only made things worse. (P.S.: The web pages became readable for me after I removed the `--force-device-scale-factor` option AND changed the Page Zoom value.)